# How to efficiently filter children based on parent's attribute

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I am looking for help with building a search bar. I have 3 database tables here: `Case` -> `Exhibit` -> `Tasking`. `Case` is `Exhibit`'s parent and `Exhibit` is `Tasking`'s parent. I have a table displaying info on a list of `Taskings` as well as their parent Id (`Exhibit`) and grandparent Id (`Case`).

I would like to be able to search thru `Taskings` based on `Case` Id. Here is my current solution (works), the display as well as searching is slow with 2000 tasking.

I think its because of the 2 find statements in the loop. The `IsMatchedTasking` is also a kinda complicated query that I am not able to write with just linq statements.

The ideal situation would be to have one query stored as an `IQueryable` which retains all the parent relationships, and pass that into the search. but since I'm using `PagedList`, it will get rid of the parent relationships when its passed into the view.

Any suggestions on how to do this properly without having to look into db context 3 times (query `Taskings` in db, filter search in db and check db to display parents attributes)?

```cs
public ActionResult GetNew(int? page, int? pageSize, string searchString)
{
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    var currUser = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
    var ps = Util.SetSessionPageSize(10, pageSize, HttpContext, "taskingGetNewPageSize");
    var output = new List<TaskingViewModel>();
    foreach (var tsk in _dbContext.Taskings) {
        if (currUser.IsMatchedTasking(tsk, _dbContext)) {
            var ex = _dbContext.Exhibits.Find(tsk.ExhibitId);
            var ca = _dbContext.Cases.Find(ex.ParentCaseId);
            output.Add(new TaskingViewModel
            {
                Tasking = tsk,
                ExhibitId = ex.Id,
                ExhibitName = ex.GetExhibitName(),
                CaseId = ca.Id,
                CasePriority = ca.GetCasePosition(_dbContext.TopTens.ToSortedList(_dbContext)),
            });
        }
    }
    var result = Search(searchString, output);
    return View(result.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize: ps));
}
```

The search function returns a new `List` of `TaskingViewModel` of matching caseIds with the `searchString` using contain.

```cs
public List<TaskingViewModel> Search(string searchString, List<TaskingViewModel> toSearch)
{
    var result = new List<TaskingViewModel>();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        return toSearch;
    foreach(var item in toSearch) {
        if (item.Id.Contains(searchString))
            result.Add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `IsMatchedTasking` - what is it?

Comment: Can you share your entity classes as well?

Comment: IsMatchedTasking is a sql query that I was not able to write in 1 linq statement. but i have sinced figured that out.  ill post the entity class for sure. Thanks guys

Comment: actually i was able to solve this with writing that query using 1 linq statement. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more details about your problem it's not easy to come with a definite answer, but here are ways to improve things:

1. Try to make this a single query that can be translated to Sql. That is possible if `IsMatchedTasking` is a condition that can be translated to sql, **and** if there are navigation properties between your entities. So the query will be something like:

```
var output = _dbContext.Taskings.Whete(x => x.UserId == userId)
.Select(x => new TaskingViewModel
            {
                TaskId = x.Id,
                TaskName = x.Name,
                ExhibitId = x.ExhibitionId,
                ExhibitName = ex.Exhibition.Name,
                CaseId = x.CaseId,
                CasePriority = x.Case.Priority,
            }.ToList()
```

But the exact thing depends on your business logic.

2. If #1 is hard, impossible, or against your architecture philosophy, then first question your architecture philosophy, but you can still make things slightly better by doing: `_dbContext.Exhibits.ToList()` and `_dbContext.Cases.ToList()` before starting the loop. In this way, all `Case`s and all `Exhibit`s will be tracked by the db context and Find() inside loop will not incur a database roundtrip. However, this is possibly not scalable, as the number of instances might be too high.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I suck at SQL queries, but I was able to pre-calculated some of the stuff that is inside IsMatchedTasking so that #1 is working. The select option is not used right now but thats also super helpful for my other functions. Thanks a lot

Comment: You were actually able to solve my problem even with my limited amount of context.